# Is it possible to bind to a public IP address on a Google Compute VM instance?

Tags: nat, google-compute-engine

I'm running a server application on a Google Compute instance which requires to use the public IP address because it's not NAT-aware/compatible (it's an MRCP if you're wondering). I'm trying to understand if such thing is possible.

I already have a public IP address assigned to my VM but I'm only able to receive traffic on the internal addresses (10.x.y.z).

Comment: I hope you aren't putting images of people's liver and pancreas in the cloud. Do you mean Media Resource Control Protocol? If it is, then you'll need to make it NAT-aware, probably by getting vendor support. The public IP is never seen or configured in the instance.

Comment: Yes Media Resource Control Protocol. It uses SIP to perform the handshake in which IP and ports are announced for the session. Not the kind of thing that play along well with NAT. So you're saying that there's no way around Google NAT. I thought so too but I had to ask.

Comment: Anything that deals with audio streams like this should have some way to configure it for NAT awareness. This is very basic functionality and it seems very unlikely that a product would be on the market without it. Contact the vendor and start yelling.

Comment: Except that an MRCP server is installed on premise and is always fronted by other media servers. It's never exposed directly.

Comment: Yes, but the corresponding SIP traffic may have to go over the Internet, depending on what you're doing. Anything that is speaking SIP should be NAT aware.

Comment: MRCP servers are typically fronted by a B2BUA. So, no, SIP traffic doesn't flow between public network and MRCP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using forwarding rules:

```
$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
NAME      REGION                   IP_ADDRESS        IP_PROTOCOL  TARGET
pf-rule1  northamerica-northeast1  www.xxx.yyy.zz1   TCP          northamerica-northeast1-a/targetInstances/target-instance-1
pf-rule2  northamerica-northeast1  www.xxx.yyy.zz2   UDP          northamerica-northeast1-a/targetInstances/target-instance-2
```

where `www.xxx.yyy.zz1` and `www.xxx.yyy.zz2` are 2 public static IP address (one for TCP and another for UDP).

Linux is kind enough to let me bind against those IP without having to add those addresses to my network interface.

This is exactly what I was looking for.

Note: instance has to be created with [`--can-ip-forward`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--can-ip-forward)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the traffic from internet, you need to allow the traffic from the ip address range that you permitted.[https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls] By default, there are implied firewall rules allow all the VPC internal traffic to your VM instance.

And for the external IP address which assigned the the VM instance isn’t configured or bind to any of the network interface inside the VM instance. So you cannot retrieve the external ip address by running the command “ip address”. There is an ip address mapping table which hold in the GCP platform for map the external ip address to VM instance, so through checking the mapping table, the traffic to external ip address will forward to the VM instance.
If your software needs to get the external ip, then you need to configure it manually.

Comment: The issue is not how to retrieve the external IP address, it's how I can bind on the public address and receive the traffic on the network interface with the public IP address.

Comment: From your message that you already assigned the external IP address to your VM instance(that means the external IP address already binded to your VM instance), then for receiving the traffic from internet,As I mentioned in the previous response. You need to add the firewall rules to allow the traffic from the internet follow the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)  _italic_ .

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be possible if you can set the Listen/BindIP or Interface in the configuration file before you start the server application.  (like IP/interface=xxxx  port=xxxx)

There might be a better way, I had a similar issue, and this worked for me with TCP/UDP.
I have not tested MRCP/SIP

To test if its possible you would:

1.Create a new VM to test on:
(Not sure what OS your running so these commands might not be accurate)

2.Then create a virtual network interface like:

ifconfig eth0:1 publicipaddress up

3.Then check it with command: ifconfig
Should look something like this:

eth0:1: flags=4163  mtu 1460
        inet xxxxxxx  netmask xxxxxxxxxx  broadcast xxxxxxxxx

1. Then start your application with listen/bind on the:  publicipaddress or interface eth0:1
2. Edit firewall to allow everything for test
3. Start firewall service then do:
4. Do this command below:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport portyourapplicationislisteningon -j DNAT --to-destination yourpublicipaddress

Handshake is received on TCP which is routed to the virtual interface you created, and it will Reply to the client the correct Public IP.

If you set you use UDP after handshake then you need to start ONE instance of your server application with your configuration file set to listen on multiple IP like: (internalIP and ExternalIP)  or (eth0 & eth0:1) this way the UDP will work correctly when it comes into internal addresses (10.x.y.z)

If your using UDP and only have the ability to set ONE Bind/Listen IP/Interface.
You can try bind/listenIP as: 0.0.0.0 which may listen/bind on all interface.
Otherwise this may not work, for my purpose the UDP only partially worked when I binded only to Public IP and added a preroute rule for the UDP, but I was not using MRCP or SIP.

Maybe someone else knows how to correctly re-route the UDP if you can only bind to one ip/interface.